# Symfony2 ManyToMany with COUNT

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine

Got this QueryBuilder in one of my repositories.

```
        $query = $em->createQueryBuilder('d')
                ->select('d, i, u, SUM(CASE WHEN t.user = :userId THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as myTickets')
                ->leftJoin('d.item','i')
                ->leftJoin('d.users','u')
                ->leftJoin('d.tickets','t')
                ->where('d.active = 1')
                ->andWhere('d.state = 1')
                ->setParameter('userId',$user->getId())
                ->orderBy('d.dateFinish', 'ASC');
```

When i execute the code, MySQL throws me this error.

> Key "premium" for array with keys "0, myTickets" does not exist

"premium" is a field of "d".

How can i recive the fields with the custom SUM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using aggregate function in your query, you get the so called `mixed result`. Mixed result normally return your object fetched with your `FROM` clause as zero index `[0]`. The rest of your result is populated based on the aliases you set for your custom fields.

`$result[0]` will return the object you want to access.

`$result['myTickets']` will return the result of your aggregate function. In this case, it's a `SUM`.

A quote from documentation:

```
SELECT u, UPPER(u.name) nameUpper FROM MyProject\Model\User u
```

> This query makes use of the UPPER DQL function that returns a scalar value and because there is now a scalar value in the SELECT clause, we get a mixed result.
>
> Conventions for mixed results are as follows:
>
> The object fetched in the FROM clause is always positioned with the key ‘0’.
>
> Every scalar without a name is numbered in the order given in the query, starting with 1.
>
> Every aliased scalar is given with its alias-name as the key. The case of the name is kept.
>
> If several objects are fetched from the FROM clause they alternate every row.

You can read more about this topic [here.](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#pure-and-mixed-results)